# How to get more detail in a mandelbrot ppm image

Tags: c

When i generate a PPM in C, that aims to represent the Mandelbrot fractal, I only get 4 pixels with colouration indicating they fall within the set. This makes sense, however when I scale it up, and have my 800X800 image with each pixel representing a number between -2->2 I get no extra detail within the fractal, it is just "4" pixels as in the first image, however each one has a size of 200x200.

I have tried: 
-using a constant in place of (a/4) and (b/4) in my second function.
-Changing dimensions of image.
-using constants within my FOR loop.
-evaluating each pixel within the main() function instead of a separate function.
-changing the value of my iterations variable when testing for inclusion within the set.

```
#include <math.h>

int inMandelbrot(int x, int y, int a, int b);
int main(){
    const int dimx = 800, dimy = 800;
    int x,y;
    FILE *mandelbrot;
    mandelbrot = fopen("mandelbrot.ppm","w");
    fprintf(mandelbrot, "P3\n%d %d\n255\n", dimx, dimy);
        for (y=-dimy/2; y< dimy/2 ;++y){
            for(x=-dimx/2;x<dimx/2;++x){
                if (inMandelbrot(x,y,dimx,dimy)==1){
                    fprintf(mandelbrot, "0 255 0\n");
                }
                else if (inMandelbrot(x,y,dimx,dimy)==0){
                    fprintf(mandelbrot, "0 0 255\n");
                }
                else if (inMandelbrot(x,y,dimx,dimy)==2){
                    fprintf(mandelbrot, "225 225 225\n");
                }
            }
        }
       (void) fclose(mandelbrot);
        return 1;
}

int inMandelbrot(int x, int y, int a, int b){
    double xnew,xold,ynew,yold;
    double Ex=(x/(a/4));
    double Ey=(y/(b/4));
    int iterations=0;
        xnew=0;
        ynew=0;
        yold=0;
        xold=0;
        while((xnew*xnew+ynew*ynew<4)&&(iterations<10000)){
                xnew=(xold*xold-yold*yold)+Ex;
                ynew=(2*xold*yold)+Ey;
                iterations++;
                xold=xnew;
                yold=ynew;
        }
        if (xnew*xnew+ynew*ynew>=4){
                iterations--;
                return 1;
        }
        else if (iterations>=10000){
            return 0;
            }
        return 2;
    }
```

I expect the output to look like the mandelbrot fractal with some degree of precision, however it only has 16 200x200 "pixels" instead of 64000 pixel sized ones.

Comment: 200x200 is consistent with `a/4` with `a=200`. Just guessing, I would change the `a` and `b` passed to the function with a smaller value.

Comment: First of all, thankyou for your help, i REALLY want to solve this, second of all, changing the value being passed to the function changed the size of the blocks of pixels, but didn't increase "resolution"

Comment: Note that in `double Ex=(x/(a/4));` the calculations are in ints and only the result is converted to double. Use `double Ex=(x/((double)a/4));`

Comment: Oh my god I love you! I KNEW it would be something like that. you have my eternal gratitude Paul :D

Comment: Using `4.0` would also force the real arithmetic.